# Self-Host SignalR and Local Http Server on the same port

Tags: c#, localhost, signalr, self-hosting

I want to host **a Self-Host SignalR process** locally on port 80 and having a local http directory hosted **on the same port** (serving files from a certain directory, mapping the directory structure to HTTP requests).

For example accessing `localhost:80/index.html` will return a html file located in a certain directory,
that also communicates with the SignalR process **on the same port**, because having different ports will cause an error in chrome browser due to [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Any idea how can I achieve it? since I cannot bind the same port with two different applications.

Comment: Usually if you want to share a port between applications, you need a program to be bound to that port and route the requests to the appropriate application.  On a Windows machine, that program is usually the Internet Information Service (IIS).  When hosting multiple websites on port 80 of the same IP, IIS would route the request based on the domain or host name.  To do this on the same hostname would require you to have both functions in the same application (as Lars points out in his answer).  You can assign multiple hostnames to the same machine, but I'm out of room to explain that.

Answer (score 3):

As long as we're talking about SignalR 2.x and you can serve your other content via WebAPI, this is possible since they both use OWIN. With MVC, things are [more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238424/run-asp-net-mvc-as-owin-middleware).

To run SignalR and WebAPI on the same port, you'd have to install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` in your SignalR applilcation and modify the Owin.IAppBuilder to use Web API:

```
public static class Startup
{
    public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
        httpConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
                                       new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});
        app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);

        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Note that you could also [use CORS](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host) to get around that browser issue.