# How to use JWT in .NET MVC (not .NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project and I authenticate users via an external service that using OAuth2.0. After user is authenticated, the service returns users' id, name and surname without any problem.

At this stage, I also need to authorize users after they login by using JWT and I use id of them to pass JWT. In addition to that I also need to prevent unathenticated users from accessing Index page by using [Authorize], etc. decorator on the action methods as in MVC and set their session expiration e.g. 2 minutes. I look at many pages and articles on the web but almost all examples or samples are for .NET Core and not suitable for .NET MVC :( There are just some examples i.e. [How to use JWT in MVC application for authentication and authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791499/how-to-use-jwt-in-mvc-application-for-authentication-and-authorization) but not detailed and missing explanations on Startup and Controller classes. As I have no experience about JWT, I need a good example covering Startup, Controller methods e.g. Login, Authenticate, etc. Is there any or could you post by completing the missing part of the example on [How to use JWT in MVC application for authentication and authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791499/how-to-use-jwt-in-mvc-application-for-authentication-and-authorization)? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60518460/12339804) be of any help?

Comment: I look at that answer and tried to apply. But encountered an error on `WebApiConfig.Register(config);` lines. I think it is due to that I do not use Web API and my MVC project type is web project. So, could you pls update that answer and post here for ASP.NET MVC? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think JWT may not be good idea for using in ASP.NET MVC app. So, I try to use OWIN Cookie as explained on https://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/. Thanks for your helps :(